# ByteArray of ByteArray as SQL Parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, arrays

I want to delete stuff that matches any `byte[]` of my array being parsed in:

```
byte[][] data
```

I know how to proceed with a simple `byte[]`, it's a different story with an array of `byte[]`.

- How do I add such a parameter (in my sample it's only `byte[]`, not `byte[][]`)
- How do I use this parameter in my SQL bit, something like

  ```
  .... 
  WHERE d IN @data ?   
  ....
  ```

Code:

```
public static void MyFunction(Transaction aTran, long Id, byte[][] data)
{
        string cmdText = ExtendedSQL.SQLQuery;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, data.Length).Value = data
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Per my understanding you will have to serialize and deserialize it while sending to DB and getting out from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store in database a `byte[][]` as a `SqlDbType.VarBinary` but it seems that you store `byte[]` only.

You want to delete all data in db that matches with multiple `byte[]` you have.

As it's stored as a binary, you'll probably need to loop on your `data[][]` to execute multiple queries.

```
    public static void MyHigherLevelFunction(Transaction aTran, long Id, byte[][] data)
    {
        foreach(byte[] oneData in data)
        {
            MyFunction(aTran, Id, oneData);
        }
    }

    public static void MyFunction(Transaction aTran, long Id, byte[] data)
    {
        string cmdText = ExtendedSQL.SQLQuery;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.VarBinary, data.Length).Value = data
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

And SQL will look like:

```
    .... 
    WHERE d = @data  
    ....
```

Comment: I was supposing so indeed.. my SQL piece looks like this:
       DELETE data FROM [dbo].[a_test]
       WHERE sha256 IN @hash